# How to initialise the autowired objects inside a jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, autowired

I have 2 applications. Application 1 and application 2. I am creating a **jar**
of application 2 and adding it to the classpath of Application 1. Application 2 has two classes. Classe A and class B. Method of class B is called in method of class A which in turn is called in the method of application 1(by importing the class A from the jar of application 2).When I'm calling the method of class B in class A, nullPointerException is coming.

I am autowiring the object of class B in class A.

```
public class A
{
  @Autowired
  Class B;
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `class A` should be spring-managed. It should be `@Bean`, `@Component`, `@Service`,...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register beans from another jar automatically you have to create your own auto-configuration. Spring Boot checks for the presence of a `META-INF/spring.factories` file within your published jar (Application 2). You should add this file to you `resources` folder in the Application 2. The file should list your configuration classes under the EnableAutoConfiguration key.

Here is example code:

```java
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class OkHttpAutoConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient defaultOkHttpClient(){
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    }
    
}
```

**spring.factories**

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.example.client.OkHttpAutoConfiguration
```

**folder structure**

[image]

Comment: This works with `spring boot 2.x`. `spring boot 3.x`  expect a file `/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` where you sum up your AutoConfiguration classes

Comment: @KSs in Application2AutoConfiguration, Application2 is simply the name of the Application or I should have a class with this name. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @nidhitiwari this is just an example, you can use whatever name you want for your class in which you configure beans

Comment: @nidhitiwari added better example

Comment: @KSs Thank you for the reply. But it's still not working. My jar is not a springBoot jar and has MVC model. Do you see any issue in that?